# Are there useful visual representations of magmas?

Tags: graph-theory, soft-question, visualization, magma

In group theory we have Cayley graphs. Are there analogous or anyway useful visual representations of magma structures?

I am unsure about how to construct a graph representing, for instance, a free magma with two generators.

Comment: Graphs like the ones in [this page](http://www.uwyo.edu/moorhouse/pub/bol/inv15.html)? I'm sure I found a paper describing their construction for more generic magmas than groups (but I admit I don't know the topic at all).